# Android - WhackAMole game

Tags: java, android

I am following the 'Android Game Programming for Dummies' book as I am new to Android and fairly new to Java. For those that have read the book, I have just completed the `animateMoles()` method (Although I'm sure that probably won't help most people).

When I run the game, the 7th mole (the rightmost) is located perfectly in place but the other 6 are gathered at the right side of the screen. I am fairly sure that I have followed the tutorial correctly and I cannot find the cause of the problem. I have shared the code on CodeTidy as it is too long to post here. I have also provided a screenshot of the problem running in the emulator.

WhackAMoleView.java - http://codetidy.com/6690/

WhackAMoleActivity.java - http://codetidy.com/6691/

Screenshot - http://postimg.org/image/hx88fxkb1/

I understand that this is A LOT of code and will appreciate anyone's help to locate the source of the problem. Thanks!

**Note**: I am not looking for alternative solutions on how to approach the game as it would make it very hard to follow the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in lines 154-167 of WhackAMoleView.java.  Looks like a copy and paste error.

```
            mole1x = (int)(55*drawScaleW);
            mole1x = (int)(155*drawScaleW);
            mole1x = (int)(255*drawScaleW);
            ...etc...
```